# How to open a new screen when tapping on a UIImageView that is in a UITableViewCell class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have my TableViewCell inside it's own class called VersionCellVC.

I have my UIImageView completely covering up the cell; so the users have no choice but to tap on the UIImageView, not the TableViewCell.

I want to perform a segue or present a vc, and I have already created the gesture recognizer and the function it calls. however, since I am in a custom subclass of UITableViewCell, I am being told by the system that I am not allowed to use the `present(vc:animate:complete)` nor the `prepare(forSegue:..:))` functions since they are not members of the UITableViewCell class.

How do I solve this without changing the UIImageView to a UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this (in your viewcontroller that contains the tableview)?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.myImageView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.myImageView?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageViewTapped(imageView:))))

    return cell
}

func imageViewTapped(imageView: UIImageView) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: imageView.convert(.zero, to: tableView)) {
        print("user tapped imageview at indexPath \(indexPath)")
    }
}
```